# Why are there dashed lines in segments?

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

I would like to learn image segmentation using SLIC algorithm in Matlab. After implementing that algorithm on some images, I saw that some lines of segments are dashed. However, I can obtain straight lines on a different image with same parameters. Required superpixel parameter is 500. Compactness factor is 20. What is the correct interpretation of that difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every image is different and algorithms often need to be tweaked on an image by image basis. Just try doing a simple binary threshold conversion

```
%matlab code
imshow(my_im < 128)
```

with different `my_im` images. you will see they are all different. One of the most difficult parts of computer-vision (which includes image segmentation) is finding ways to tune the parameters automatically without trial and error type approaches